# Rewriting .csv data to file creates artifacted first column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm taking data in csv from multiple REST endpoints, trying to add column headers to the data, and change the delimiters in the data from semicolons (;) to commas (,) so they can be formatted correctly by excel.

For note: x in the code below is a list of the link URIs and the ellipsis replaces the code used to discover and pull the links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import parse
import logging
import csv
...
...
for link in links:
    linkContent = urlopen(link)
    htmlBytes = linkContent.read()
    htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("utf-8")
    targetFile = open(str(x[link]) + '.csv', 'w')
    targetFile.write('Date;StartTime;EndTime;Environment;Domain;DeployID;Module;Status;BuildVersion;DeployType;DeployStart\n')
    targetFile.write(htmlString)
    targetFile.close()

for file in x:
    with open(str(x[file]) + '.csv', newline='') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile,delimiter=";")
        data = [line for line in csvFile]

    datalen= len(data)
    for i in range(datalen):
        data[i] = data[i].replace(";", ",")
        data[i] = data[i].replace(" ","")

    with open(str(x[file]) + '.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        w=csv.writer(csvFile,delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar=' ')
        w.writerows([data])
```

Unfortunately this produces an unnecessary comma before every row following the first and I'm not sure why.

i.e.

Date ,StartTime ,EndTime ...
, 2016-07-12 ,03:11 ,03:21, ...

This has excel display all blanks for the first row, and starts displaying the data in the row after. Essentially shifting all data one row to the right.

There's probably a few unnecessary parameters and/or arguments in the code from my trying to get it to parse correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you replacing `;` with `,` since you already changed the delimiters?

Comment: Note that inserting a `,` in your lines in a file delimited with `,` will lead to column alignment problems. The editor you used to open the file will make columns at every `,`

Comment: The files weren't originally delimited by a `,` they were delimited by `;`. I did this so the files can just be opened in excel without error.

Comment: I'm hoping for excel to make a new column at every comma, I'm just confused why my output begins each new row/line with a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually adding `,` to the file will cause column alignment problems as the manually inserted `,`s will clash with the ones inserted by the `csv.writer` as delimiter.

Changing the delimiter from `;` to `,` will not require an extra `replace(";", ",")`. It is sufficient to change the delimiters in the `csv.reader` and `writer` objects.

The following should do what you intend:

```
for file in x:
    with open(str(x[file]) + '.csv', newline='') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";")
        data = [row for row in reader]
        #                      ^^^^^^ use reader not csvFile

    with open(str(x[file]) + '.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        w=csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar=' ')
        w.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thank you that's is a more efficient way of writing the code, however it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I'm still getting a `,` at the beginning of every line after the first.

Comment: @Ryan.Patrick I've updated the code. You were using `csvFile` instead of `reader`